# html/css - Input text area, move to/break new line once width is reached

Tags: html, css, input, line-breaks

I am building a chat UI and I have figured out how to break the message text when the width is reached using `word-break: break-all` in my css script for received and sent messages. I can not figure how to do it to my actual input field where the user writes the text. It all goes in one line while typing instead of breaking like it would sending a text message on a smart phone.

I have tried adding `word-break: break-all` into my `&__textbox` method but it doesn't seem to be working and I am not sure why. Can someone point out why it's not working? I have found examples of another UI doing it but I can't seem to find what is allowing linebreaks in the input field.

Here is my css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 62.5%;

}
.chatbox-avatar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: absolute;
  transition: .1s ease-out;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 1px;
}

.chatbox-avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.c-chat-window {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;

 
  &__messages {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 68px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 34px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    width: 100%;


  }
  
  &__compose {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    border: none;




  }
  
  &__text-box {
    flex: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border:0;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 0 10px;





  }
  
  &__button {
    border: none;
    background: orangered;
    padding:  0 15px;
    color: white;
  }
  
  &__container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50px;  
    word-break: break-all






  }
  
  &__header {
    background: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .chat-partner-name {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 0 0 80px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
}
  
  &__target {
    height: 40px;
    background: orangered;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    
  }
  
  &__message {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    

    
    &--sent {
      background: orangered;
      color: white;
      margin-left: auto;
      word-break: break-all


    }
    
    &--received {
      background: lightgrey;
      margin-right: auto;
    word-break: break-all


    }
  }
  
  &__notification {
    background: dodgerblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
    right: 0;
    top: -15px;
    display:flex;
    
    &::after {
      content: '';
      display:inline-block;
      margin: auto;
      height:5px;
      width:5px;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
      top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
      

    }
  }
  
  &--hide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and my html:

```
<main>
  <div class="c-chat-window__container">
    <div class="c-chat-window__target">Chatbot</div>

    <div class="c-chat-window__notification c-chat-window--hide"></div>
    <div class="c-chat-window c-chat-window--hide"> 
      <div class="c-chat-window__header">
        <div class="chat-partner-name">
        <a target>Chatbot</a>
      </div>
      <div class="chatbox-avatar">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/mfreak"><img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/2449e413ade8b0c72d0a15d153febdeb?s=512&d=https://codepen.io/assets/avatars/user-avatar-512x512-6e240cf350d2f1cc07c2bed234c3a3bb5f1b237023c204c782622e80d6b212ba.png" /></a> 
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-chat-window__messages">
      </div>
      <div class="c-chat-window__compose">
        <input type="text" class="c-chat-window__text-box" placeholder="Write message...">  
        <button class="c-chat-window__button" type="submit">Send
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a "textarea" input instead of a "text" input? It line breaks automatically

Comment: @Shiverz No reason, just missed that. Is that supposed to line break the messages in the body of the chatbox automatically? Because it doesn't do line breaks while inputting. When typing, it still just stays in one line.

Comment: Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwseznkr/) using a textarea instead of a text input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have line breaks, you should use the `<textarea>` element.